# Downloading a ttf file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, truetype, open-uri

```
link = 'http://protext.hackerrank.com/static/gen/font_a_21fb3d1d1a91a7e80dff456205f3380b.ttf'
```

If you visit this URL in your browser it should download a .ttf file. However, I haven't been able to find a way to download said file using Ruby, or even access the information within.

Things I've tried:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'
```

-

```
File.open('font_0.ttf', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.write open(url).read
end
```

-

```
download = open(url)
IO.copy_stream(download, '~/font_0.ttf')
```

-

```
Net::HTTP.start("http://protext.hackerrank.com") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/static/gen/font_a_21fb3d1d1a91a7e80dff456205f3380b.ttf")

  p resp.body
}
```

I've also tried most of the above with Nokogiri's `parse`.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to some local test, you need to specify a header field `Cookie: X-VALID=TRUE` to pass the server check.

```
require 'open-uri'
data = open("http://protext.hackerrank.com/static/gen/font_a_21fb3d1d1a91a7e80dff456205f3380b.ttf", 
            "Cookie" => "X-VALID=TRUE").read
```

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out over this for hours. Thank you! By the way, how were you able to find out that you must include the `Cookie: X-VALID=TRUE `?

Comment: Open "Developer Tools -> Network" panel in Chrome, visit that URL, from the network panel, right click on the URL entry -> "Copy as cURL". Now you have a cURL command to mimic the browser behavior. And you can try to reduce the header parameters to see which set is required.